# C++ recording a source location in mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

In C, I commonly have a wrapped mutex whose lock operation takes arguments

```
lock( const char *fn, int line );
```

so that the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` of the holder can be recorded in the data structure.

The basic lockable description in C++ requires a `lock()` that takes no arguments.

Is there a reasonable way in C++ to get file and line recorded in a mutex that is being taken under `lock_guard`?

Comment: Wrap `lock_guard`.

Comment: Eventually you'll be able to add a default [`source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) parameter.  Until then, no, you can't do this with just `std::lock_guard`.